# GA4: Data API Response returns 1 row only for 2 (or more) events which have exactly similar data

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have an event that is sent twice that I want to retrieve from GA4 using `RunReportRequest`.

The problem is, because both events has the exactly same data (same parameter values), the response I get from `RunReportRequest` shows only `row_count:1`, whereas I expect `row_count:2`, considering my `eventCount` is 2.

The sample data is constructed as follows and sent to GA4.
The only different value is that of `Param2`.
`Param1` to `Param9` are custom dimensions.

```
{
    "client_id": "x",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "EVENT_NAME",
            "params": {
                "engagement_time_msec": "30",
                "session_id": "3",
                "Param1": "Lorem",
                "Param2": "ipsum_1",
                "Param3": "dolor",
                "Param4": "sit",
                "Param5": "amet",
                "Param6": "consectetur",
                "Param7": "adipiscing",
                "Param8": "elit",
                "Param9": "Nunc"
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "client_id": "x",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "EVENT_NAME",
            "params": {
                "engagement_time_msec": "30",
                "session_id": "3",
                "Param1": "Lorem",
                "Param2": "ipsum_2",
                "Param3": "dolor",
                "Param4": "sit",
                "Param5": "amet",
                "Param6": "consectetur",
                "Param7": "adipiscing",
                "Param8": "elit",
                "Param9": "Nunc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The response I get from `BatchRunReportsRequest`'s second `runReportRequest`  is where the it shows incomplete number of rows.
The value of `Param1`, `Param8` and `Param9` are exactly the same in the two sets of data above.

```
reports {
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param1"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param2"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param3"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param4"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param5"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param6"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param7"
  }
  rows {
    dimension_values {
      value: "Lorem"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "ipsum_1"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "dolor"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "sit"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "amet"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "consectetur"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "adipiscing"
    }
  }
  rows {
    dimension_values {
      value: "Lorem"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "ipsum_2"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "dolor"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "sit"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "amet"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "consectetur"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "adipiscing"
    }
  }
  row_count: 2
  metadata {
    currency_code: "JPY"
    time_zone: "Asia/Tokyo"
  }
  kind: "analyticsData#runReport"
}
reports {
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param1"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param8"
  }
  dimension_headers {
    name: "customEvent:Param9"
  }
  rows {
    dimension_values {
      value: "Lorem"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "elit"
    }
    dimension_values {
      value: "Nunc"
    }
  }
  row_count: 1
  metadata {
    currency_code: "JPY"
    time_zone: "Asia/Tokyo"
  }
  kind: "analyticsData#runReport"
}
kind: "analyticsData#batchRunReports"
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? Are there any workaround?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the sample data from GA?

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics reports group dimensions by unique values & sum up metrics. For example, let's say Report A has dimensions of `country`, `region`, and `city`; Report A will have a row like `South Africa`, `Western Cape`, and `Cape Town` ([See Dimensions  to learn more](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimensions)).

Let's say Report B has just one dimension of `country`. Report B will not have separate rows for each city in `South Africa`. Report B will have just one row for `South Africa`.

In your example, `Lorem`, `elit`, and `Nunc` are shared between the two events. Google Analytics aggregates them to one row. You can add the metric `eventCount` to both reports. The first report will have 1 `eventCount` per row. The second report will have 2 `eventCount` for the second row.